# Does socket.io have raw WebSocket access like sockjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, sockjs

[Sockjs](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node) and [socket.io](http://socket.io/) are both JavaScript libraries for node.js that automatically choose which transport protocol can be used on top of HTTP.

I know that sockjs also provides a direct WebSocket access, so a sockjs server can be used with the associated socksjs client library or with a native WebSocket access.

For instance, if I have a sockjs-based server at `http://localhost:8081/echo` I can use a direct WebSocket access with the URL `ws://localhost:8081/echo/websocket`

Does socket.io also provide a direct/raw WebSocket access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, socket.io does not have raw websocket transport due to higher level abstraction (multiplexing, events, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [engine.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/engine.io) which is a lower level abstraction which serves as the base for socket.io.

> The recommended framework for building realtime applications is Socket.IO, since it provides fundamental features for real-world applications such as multiplexing, reconnection support, etc.

Engine is to Socket.IO what Connect is to Express. An essential piece for building realtime frameworks, but something you probably won't be using for building actual applications.